# Installer does not close after running custom action

Tags: wix

I've made my Wix installer run an application after finishing installation. This now works, but the installer does not close. Every time I click the Finish button, the application is started once more.
I'd like the application to be run async and then installer terminate.

This is how I did it in Wix;

```
    <UI>
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Order="1" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch $(var.ProductName) Launcher" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" FileKey="LnLauncherExe" ExeCommand="" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="yes" />
```

An other problem I have is that the checkbox does not show up. I can live with this, but if someone can spot why, it would be nice to get fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed this How To article? http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

Comment: Yan, yes I have. The problem is not the launch of the application but rather the installer not closing when pressing the Finish button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following seems to work;

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
```

Comment: How does your custom action get executed though if you are no longer tying it to the Finish button?

Comment: Apparently I didn't read it close enough.  You only added that line you didn't replace the one you mention in your question above.  This works.